# How to setup environment for front end coding?

Tags: javascript, css, frontend

I'm getting around to doing a few front end coding in CSS and javascript.

But the caching of css, javascript, and html files is killing  me slowly.  Whenever I make a change, I try everything to get the updated files to refresh, but the old version keep coming back.  Of course, this is a great feature in the production version, but in development, it's driving me nuts.

I found an extension "CSS Refresh" that does a good job of refreshing CSS, but html and javascript can still be a problem.

I'm using mainly chrome and occasionally firefox for testing.

Comment: CTRL+F5 to do a forced refresh

Comment: Works in IE + FF, but chrome seems to not like it, especially for images

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you try disabling cache in Firefox?

If you are looking for an addon
https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/10338/

Or as another user stated use Web Developer Toolbar
https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/60/

Comment: Although this wasn't the source of my problem (it was database caching set up by my server).  I marked this as answer since I wasn't aware of this tool and it looks pretty useful.

Answer (score 1):

I find the only way to guarantee a refresh when you release a new version of a web application is to rename the relevant files.  Ideally use some sort of version number on the javascript/css (e.g. script.1.0.3.4.js).

With a bit of effort you can automate all this into the build process using the feature to auto increment an assembly's version.

Comment: Really?  Man there's got to be an easier way.  I tried the Web Developer Toolbar suggested here and it still doesn't work.  I changed a line of code in a javascript, but when I look at the loaded js in firebug, it's the old one.  CTR;-5 doesn't help.  ---Where is Firefox getting these old files from?

Comment: The CTR-5 etc is just a development solution - you can't expect your clients/visitors to do this every time you change your javascript.  For this renaming is (as far as I know) then only safe solution to force reload of the script/css.  For development purposes CTR-5 etc really should work - if it's not then perhaps you're caching the script elsewhere (e.g. in a proxy?).  If you clear browsing data from the options dialog and it's still not changing - then it's definitely being cached at another point along the line.

Comment: So I double checked my settings file.  Turns out I was doing database caching and forgot to remove this option. Doh!

Answer (score 1):

I find this quite helpful when doing JavaScript developing in chrome:

*Another interesting option is to open a new incognito window (ctrl+shift+n). This window won't use any stored cookies, cached content, or dns resolutions.*

Source: https://superuser.com/questions/220179/cache-refresh-in-chrome/220186#220186

Answer (score 0):

On Firefox you have the Web Developper toolbar than can disable caching for a particular website. I also recommend the Firebug extension if you are not already using it.